# Who can interact with Google Directory API?

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-endpoints, google-directory-api

The question look very easy to answer but the [documentation](https://developers.google.com/admin-sdk/directory/) is not really clear about that. I am using OAuth 2.0 to authorize requests but in the end, only administrators are able to use APIs, normal users will get an error. Am i missing something in my configuration or simply normal users are not allowed to use Directory API? As far as I can tell, it should not be possible but I see many reasons why instead it should be. For instance, in my applications I'd like to handle permissions based on user's OU. Unfortunately I couldn't find a way to do that because every call to the API must be authorized by an authenticated user. But what if that user is not an administrator?

For instance, if I try to execute this [API example](https://developers.google.com/admin-sdk/directory/v1/reference/users/get) as a normal user I get the following error:

> > "Not Authorized to access this resource/api".

Whereas with an administrator account I can successfully retrieve the JSON result.

Comment: Organizational Unit, see [here](https://developers.google.com/admin-sdk/directory/v1/reference/orgunits).

Comment: Is it a Google Apps Marketplace app you're talking about?

Comment: Google App Engine application.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It makes sense that only the admin of the domain can use the Directory API (which is a subset of the Admin SDK) - only the domain admin has access to all the user data.

You can access the Directory API for the relevant domain using a service account - which will give you full access that was granted in the scopes by the domain admin when allowing your app. And afterwards you'll decide on your server-side which features you want to expose to "regular" users, and which you expose to the admins only.

But again, in order to do that, you need to find a way to implement a service account mechanism in your app.

Comment: You dont have to use service accounts or add the app to the domain. Just do an oauth flow to store the refresh token of an admin. Admin enters the page for that servlet once during deploy.

Comment: Doesn't token expire after a while? Also what do you mean with "you need to find a way to implement service account"?

Comment: I'm not sure about the way @ZigMandel described - never went down that road. What we're doing is getting permissions from the admin, and then using them for all users while filtering what regular users get. This document should help: https://developers.google.com/admin-sdk/directory/v1/guides/delegation

Comment: My point is, delegation isnt needed. Once you have the admin refresh token for that scope, the app has access.

Answer (score 0):

I was commenting on the other answer since I think using delegation is overkill here and has security implications.
Just use regular server flow oauth2, no need for 2-step oauth.
make a page in your app for the domain admin to enter and set up the app permissions
in there, make an oauth flow to capture the refresh token of that admin user.
then follow the oauth docs to get an access token from that refresh token
there are google classes that do all that for you

To try it out quickly or to skip the oauth flow implementation and just hardcode a refresh token, go to the https://developers.google.com/oauthplayground/
there, add the needed scope for example https://www.googleapis.com/auth/admin.directory.user
follow until step 2, where it gives you a refresh token.
Of course step 1 & 2 need to be done from an admin account that has access to the permissions you need.
continue to step 3 to prove that this actually works, by making a call to the api you want.

Comment: What kind of security implications? What could happen? The only problem I see is if someone finds a way to steal the private key.

Comment: you are right, the security implications are about the same. But when adding scopes to a domain requires a more complicated instalation involving a superadmin, and gives you the ability to impersonate more users, possibly reading their personal account data (Depends on the scopes added), while my suggestion only requires permission to a single account which the user can see in their "security" settings and revoke, and doesnt delegate the access to other users in the domain.

Comment: Could you please provide an example of server flow oauth2? With any API, I can't seem to find it on the Google documentation.

Comment: https://developers.google.com/accounts/docs/OAuth2#webserver or https://developers.google.com/accounts/docs/OAuth2WebServer